# Toggle form in nested v-for loop in VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have a list of nested comments. Under each comment, I'd like to add a "reply" button that, when click, show a reply form.

For now, everytime I click a "reply" button, it shows the form. But the thing is, I'd like to show only one form on the whole page. So basically, when I click on "reply" it should close the other form alreay opened and open a new one under the right comment.

**Edit :**

So I was able to make some slight progress. Now I'm able to only have one active form opening on each level of depth in the nested loop. Obviously, what I'm trying to do now is to only have one at all.
What I did was emitting an event from the child component and handle everything in the parent component. The thing is, it would work great in a non-nested comment list but not so much in my case...

Here is the new code:

In the parentComponent, I have a handleSelected method as such:

```
handleSelected (id) {
  if(this.selectedItem === id)
    this.selectedItem = null;
  else
    this.selectedItem = id;
},
```

And my childComponent:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="comment">
        <div v-bind:style=" iAmSelected ? 'background: red;' : 'background: none;' ">
            <p>{{ comment.author.name }}<br />{{ comment.created_at }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
            <button class="button" @click="toggle(comment.id)">Répondre</button>
            <button class="button" @click="remove(comment.id)">Supprimer</button>

            <div v-show="iAmSelected">
                <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Votre réponse</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" v-model="fields.comment"></textarea>
                        <div v-if="errors && errors.comment" class="text-danger">{{ errors.comment[0] }}</div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>

                    <div v-if="success" class="alert alert-success mt-3">
                        Votre réponse a bien été envoyée !
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="comment.hasReply">
            <div style="margin-left: 30px;">
                <comment v-for="comment in comments"
                    :key="comment.id"
                    :comment="comment" @remove-comment="remove"
                    :is-selected="selectedItem" @selected="handleSelected($event)">
                </comment>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import comment from './CommentItem'

    export default {
        name: 'comment',
        props: {
            isSelected: Number,
            comment: {
                required: true,
                type: Object,
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                comments: null,
                fields: {},
                errors: {},
                success: false,
                loaded: true,
                selectedItem: null,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            iAmSelected () {
                return this.isSelected === this.comment.id;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            remove(id) {
                this.$emit('remove-comment', id)
            },
            toggle(id) {
                this.$emit('selected', id);
            },
            handleSelected(id) {
              if(this.selectedItem === id)
                this.selectedItem = null;
              else
                this.selectedItem = id;
            },
        },
        mounted(){
            if (this.comment.hasReply) {
                axios.get('/comment/replies/' + this.comment.id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.comments = response.data
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: does changing  `v-if="reply == comment.id"` to `v-if="reply === comment.id"` help at all?

Comment: @wheelmaker Unfortunately no, it didn't work :/ I made some progress though, I edited my original post.

Comment: Have you considered using `vuex` for state management?  One nice clean data store you can access, mutate and fire off actions from any component in your app.

Comment: @wheelmaker Actually I solved this issue by using a BusEvent, everything works now! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it solved, sounds like bus events might be the best solution for you but if you find yourself reaching for them too often... be sure to check out `vuex`, you won't regret it.